# 文字列の配列に対してStringクラスのメソッドが呼べるのはなぜ？

Tags: powershell

PowerShellでは文字列の配列に対して String クラスのメソッド、例えば `Replace()` などが呼び出せるようですが、これはどういう仕様によるものなのでしょうか？

```
PS C:\> $arr = "abc","abc"

PS C:\> $arr
abc
abc

PS C:\> $arr.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                         
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                         
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array  

PS C:\> $arr.Replace('b', '_')
a_c
a_c
```

`GetType()` で型を取得してもただの `Object[]` ですし、Get-Member で見てもこのメソッドは存在しません。Count のようにエイリアスが追加されているというわけでもないようです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell 3.0 以降、コレクション自身には存在せず、その要素に存在するメソッド・プロパティを呼び出そうとすると、各要素に対する呼び出しに変換されます。

Foreach ステートメントの簡略構文と同様、コレクションの要素の型が混在していても構いませんし、一部の要素にだけ存在するメソッド・プロパティを呼び出すこともできます。

```
PS C:\> [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Range(32,10).ToChar($null)  #配列でないコレクション

!
"
#
$
%
&
'
(
)

PS C:\> ([DateTime]::Now, [TimeSpan]::FromHours(1)).Ticks  #異なる型だがどちらも実装している
636270872544918849
36000000000

PS C:\> ([DateTime]::Now, [TimeSpan]::FromHours(1)).TimeOfDay  #DateTimeしか実装していない


Days              : 0
Hours             : 14
Minutes           : 38
Seconds           : 51
Milliseconds      : 953
Ticks             : 527319534503
TotalDays         : 0.610323535304398
TotalHours        : 14.6477648473056
TotalMinutes      : 878.865890838333
TotalSeconds      : 52731.9534503
TotalMilliseconds : 52731953.4503
```

MSDNのドキュメントでは [about_Methods](https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/hh847878.aspx) の「スカラー オブジェクトおよびコレクションのメソッド」に記載があります。